# How do I update range of timestamps in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp

Some of my data stored in elastic moved far into the future because I mixed up seconds and milliseconds thing. I need to divide all timestamps from the specified range by 1000.

I know how to get the needed data but I don't know how to update them.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "message.timestamp": {
        "gte": "+50798-06-20T00:27:37"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Use POST to send an update request. I used _update_by_query request, specified the range and wrote a script that parses string datetime to timestamp which is then divided by 1000 to convert to seconds.

```
POST myindex/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "message.timestamp": {
        "gte": "+50000-06-20T00:27:37"
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(\"+yyyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss\", Locale.getDefault()); long timestamp = format.parse(ctx._source.message.timestamp).getTime(); ctx._source.message.timestamp = timestamp / 1000;",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```